# object C Library project which contains images to xamarin.ios Binding Project

Tags: xcode, c#-4.0, xamarin

I am trying to bind the objective C library project for xamarin.ios. Library contains some images in it. How do I Add those images in binding pocess??

Comment: you want to add images in static libaray ?

Comment: Yes, only static library will use that image. How to do it?

Comment: you need to add Bundle in Static library to access images.

Comment: You mean I need to add it in Xcode static library. Do I need to add that same image in Xamarin Binding project also?

Comment: no you need to add it in Xcode static library

Comment: I will try adding images in xcode static library.

Comment: Can you share me any examples how to add it static library?